# Delete and invalid pointer

Tags: c++, memory, glibc, delete-operator

```
int main()
{
    char* a=new char[20];  
    cin>>a;  
    cout<<" character at 7-th position."<<a[6];  
    delete a+4;  
    cout<<a[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
1234567894567
```

Output:

```
character at 7-th position.6  
*** glibc detected *** ./test free() invalid pointer:....
```

Now I have 3 questions

1. Is it correct that `delete a+4` will only delete the character at `a+4`?
2. If answer to previous one is yes then what happens to `a[0]`.We should get the output.
3. to delete a chunk of memory we should write `delete[]`.But in this case how come all the elements are deleted?

Comment: You can't "delete a char".

Comment: So how can I get that memory back??

Comment: We probably should have a canonical answer to "What pointer values may be used with the C++ delete operator?"

Comment: Uh, delete the array of characters. You specifically say "to delete a chunk of memory we should write delete[]". Yes, this.

Comment: As the I am going to delete a+4 the memory becomes corrupted and then we can't access any element of that same chunk.Is it so??

Answer (score 4):

There are only three types of pointer values you can pass as the operand of `delete`:

1. Null pointer values.  They simply get ignored.
2. A complete scalar (not array) object previously allocated with `new`, either of:

   - The exact pointer returned by `new`
   - A pointer to a base subobject of the pointer returned by `new`, if and only if the base subobject's type has a `virtual` destructor

Any these pointer values should NEVER ever be passed to scalar `delete`:

1. The result of array `new` or `new[]` (use `delete[]` instead)
2. The result of `malloc` or any other allocator which is not `new`
3. The address of an object with automatic or static storage duration
4. The address of a member subobject or array element
5. Uninitialized pointer values
6. Pointers to already-deleted objects

If you break this rule, you get *undefined behavior*.  That means your program might crash with a nice message that an invalid delete was detected.  Or your data might get corrupted, saved in your data files, sent to your boss, shown to the customer, and later you get fired.  So don't break the rule.

Your code falls into category "NEVER DO THIS #4".

---

The reason it works this way is because an implementation can (and most do) track extra information called metadata along with each allocated block.  For example, the size of the block, which is pretty important for enabling reuse.  There is no metadata for part of a block, and there may not be any way to find the metadata from a pointer into the middle.

Comment: If this starts becoming an canonical question I'll gladly add quotes from the Standard.

Answer (score 1):

1. No.  `delete` is the opposite of `new`.  You essentially delete the same pointer that you get when allocating. Deleting other pointers is undefined, hence your "invalid pointer" error. If you allocated an array, you have to use `delete[]`.  Right now, you are leaking ("not freeing") that memory.  So use `delete [] a;` after you are done.
2. Not really applicable.
3. Because that is how C++ works.  It is the operation you use to free an array you allocated.

It *appears* that you want to remove a character from a string, then print the string.  If that is what you are after, consider using a `std::string` and using its `remove` member function.  Regardless, `a[0]` is a `char`, not a `char*`, the latter of which is a C style string.  You should

```
cout << a;
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks..But I can't understand the last line of your answer.What do you mean by you should...I mean you are saying that if you wan't to print a string then do cout<<a isn,t it?

Comment: If you want to print a string, instead of a single character, then you pass a pointer to the first character and it prints until it finds a null byte (the end of string marker).  If you just want a single character printed, then you're doing it right.