# C++ Delete[] giving error in VS 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, delete-operator

I am trying to remove a `const char *

```
int len = str.length();
const char * c = str.c_str();
unsigned short * s = new unsigned short[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    s[i] = c[i] - '0'; // I dislike this cheat
}


delete[] c; // Gives error.
```

`c` is also not used after it is deleted.
I am newer to C++ and I am trying to learn the delete operator and it is not going so well :/

Comment: You don't need c, you can use `str[i]` directly.

Comment: Related (although I haven't covered the `delete[]` details, the same principles apply): http://stackoverflow.com/a/24522778/103167

Answer (score 4):

I don't support the usage of `new` and `delete` in cases like these, but to point out your error, you're deleting memory not allocated via `new`.

You probably meant to write `delete[] s;`
(Because `s` is allocated via `new[]`)

Also, `s` could easily be a `std::vector<unsigned short>`:

```
// Initializes a vector of unsigned shorts with a specified size.
std::vector<unsigned short> s(len);
```

Comment: It tells me that in `delete[] s` s needs to be a pointer type, and when I put `&s` it gives me an error when I run it.

Comment: If you changed your code to use the `vector` solution, then the `delete` would be redundant. That's sort of the point~

Comment: the input I am getting is a string, and from that string I am splitting each character (which is a number 0-9) and putting it into an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
const char * c = str.c_str();
delete[] c; // Gives error.
```

`c` is a pointer to the contents of `str` that's still owned and managed by the `str` object itself, may not be dynamically allocated (e.g. it could be a pointer to a Short String Optimisation buffer internal to the `str` object), let alone by `new[]`, and even if it happens to be the `str` object will do a `delete[]` when it goes out of scope or has copied the data to a larger buffer for whatever reason.  Summarily, after calling `c_str()` you can use the pointer until the `str` object is resized or "destructed", but don't need to do any clean-up yourself.

---

Looking at the rest of your code...

```
int len = str.length();
const char * c = str.c_str();
unsigned short * s = new unsigned short[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    s[i] = c[i] - '0'; // I dislike this cheat
}
delete[] c; // Gives error.
```

...the only error per se is that you `delete[] c`, but you don't `delete[] s` and probably should somewhere, some time after it's no longer needed.

That said, you can use `std::vector` to store the ASCII codes like this (for C++11):

```
std::vector<unsigned short> s;

for (char c : str)
    s.push_back(c - '0');
```

If you don't have C++11, then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    s.push_back(c[i] - '0');
```

...or if you want to try *iterators*...

```
std::vector<unsigned short> s;
for (std::string::const_iterator i = str.begin(); i != str.end(); ++i)
    s.push_back(*i - '0');
```

You could also use `std::copy` with an inserter, more declarative but a bit over-the-top IMHO:

```
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(s));
```

Comment: do you mean `delete[] s` or is there a `delete s[]`?

Comment: @MichaelMitchell yes I did `delete[] s` - fixed.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

No need to delete c, it's only a a pointer to an array (that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters of "str").

The array is still stored in variable "str".